# What to do after wipe?

Tags: 12.04, windows-8, 13.10

I have a major problem in regard to Ubuntu 13.10.  Today I was installing in on my ubuntu 12.04/windows 8.1 pc.  I selected the option of installing along side of ubuntu 12.04 and windows 8.1.  After installing I tried to boot into windows 8.  IT WAS GONE!  Ubuntu 12.04 was gone as well!  Now I was frustrated and tried to get to my recovery partion.  That was gone too!  Is there anyway to get my data back?

Thx,
Andrew

Comment: Also i was wondering if anyone else was haveing problem installing google chrome on ubuntu 13.10

Comment: please create a new Askubuntu question for each subject (don't mix all your questions on the same page).

Comment: ok thx for the info

Answer (score 0):

Write a Live Distribution on a DVD and explore the partitions to be able to recover any data left on the Hard Disk devices (Windows & Linux partitions). In the Live Distribution install `extundelete` or any equivalent package to recover your deleted data from Linux **ext** partitions.
**You can't recover a file** if it have been overwritten for 7 times or more.
If you have any doubt write them here in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot on an Ubuntu disk, choose "`try Ubuntu`", and use the file browser to check if you can do a backup of your files.
2. If still not good, try to recover your lost files via [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step).